# How to refactor the code which uses a map passing everywhere?

Tags: java, dictionary, refactoring

Now I'm refactoring a legacy Java project, and have some problems now.

It defines a class names `DataHolder` which extends from `Map<String,Object>`, and as parameters to passing through classes and methods.

```
public class DataHolder extends Map<String,Object> {
}

public class Cls1 {
    public void execute(DataHolder data) {
        data.put("key1", someData);
    }
}


public class Cls2 {
    public void execute(DataHolder data) {
        Object someData = data.get("key1");
    }
}

...
```

There are more than 30 classes and 100 methods are using this `DataHolder` instance, and for most of them, it's the only parameter.

When a method generates some values which may need in other methods, it just put them into the data holder. And if it needs some, it just get them from the data holder.

The code is hard to read, to test, and even to refactor. I'm trying to refactor it, but don't know how to do it.

Is there any good idea?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Sounds like DataHolder should be a field and the classes's execute methods should be different methods instead.

Comment: The 30 classes could all extend a common class which has a reference to this DataHolder. You could then erase the DataHolder parameters in all the functions.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, Intellij IDEA

Answer (score 2):

DataHolder seems to be a sort of singleton, which does create issues to understand and test the code. The general principles that can be used to get rid of singletons can probably be applied to your use case. Here are two examples applied to your execute methods.

`Cls2#execute` only needs `data.get("key1")` - a first step to the refactoring process would be to pass just that to the method:

```
cls2.execute(dataHolder);
//becomes
cls2.execute(dataHolder.get("key1"));
```

That way you can remove all the "read-only" dependencies. For more complex examples, where several values are needed, it may make sense to pass an object containing all the relevant information (which will hopefully be more specialised than your DataHolder).

As for `Cls1#execute` it essentially creates a new value so should return it instead of placing it in a global data structure:

```
public void execute(DataHolder data) { data.put("key1", someData); }
```

should really be:

```
public Object execute() { return someData; }
```

A very interesting piece to read: [Google guide on Writing Testable Code](http://misko.hevery.com/attachments/Guide-Writing%20Testable%20Code.pdf).

Comment: You are right. The whole DataHolder issue seems to hide that there is actually no architecture behind the project. I also bet @Freewind knows that and we pity him for it :)

Answer (score 1):

This is somehow a meta question so I will not write the actual code here.
One approach would be to use the Singleton pattern. Basically it sais that you have a class which intitialises the DataHolder object in a static field and returns this object everytime you need it.
You could erase all the DataHolder parameters in your functions and just make a call like that at the beginning `DataHolder data = DataHolderSingleton.getInstance()`.
If something is unclear about the usage of Singeltons or the benefit of this approach I will try to extend this answer.

Comment: That just replaces one global state by another - it won't really make the code easier to understand or more testable...

Comment: I guess that will only be accomplished by getting completely rid of the DataHolder. Since this is not likely to happen I thought of a way to make it at least a bit better.